# Unix server time is wrong on reboot but corrects itself a few minutes later (this messes up my boot logs)

Tags: boot, 22.04, date

I don't really know why this is happening but when the server is booted, the date/time is always ahead of reality by a few hours, but it fixes itself after while. But this means my initial startup logs are written in the wrong sequence.  This is a VM running under ESXi 6.7

For example, consider the following shell commands which I execute right after boot. The initial timestamps are all wrong until they are magically corrected a short time later. My timezones for root and all users are UTC.

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
```

```
user@server:~$ while true
> do
> date
> sleep 1
> done
Thu Feb 22 12:21:03 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:04 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:05 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:06 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:07 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:08 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:09 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:10 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:11 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:12 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:13 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:14 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:15 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:16 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:17 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:18 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:19 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:20 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:21 AM UTC 2024
Thu Feb 22 12:21:22 AM UTC 2024
Wed Feb 21 07:38:13 PM UTC 2024
Wed Feb 21 07:38:14 PM UTC 2024
Wed Feb 21 07:38:15 PM UTC 2024
Wed Feb 21 07:38:16 PM UTC 2024
Wed Feb 21 07:38:17 PM UTC 2024
Wed Feb 21 07:38:18 PM UTC 2024
```

Comment: try set the clock   ``sudo hwclock -w''

Comment: Did it but it didn't fix the problem.  Everything can be set correctly, bios clock, Linux clock, but the moment I reboot, the initial few minutes, the date/time is ahead by several hours and then it's fixed after a short time

Comment: try "man hwclock"